# jquery animate website height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good Morning,

I am creating a website which as a lot of dynamic content and some pages are smaller than the screen and some are larger than the screen (So it uses overflow to display a scroll bar so you can scroll to the content.)

I'm looking to see if it is possible to animate the screen so that when the content is larger than the screen and the user has 'scrolled down' to see the content to when the content has changed and it is now smaller than the screen...

At the moment, the content just jumps to the lowest point when the content is reduced.. I would like a smooth animation to this point.

**Example:**

*For this, Let's say the screen height is 768px.*

Content is around 1400px long and the user has scrolled down the page to view the bottom of the content.. the user now clicks on a link which makes the content only 300px and therefore does not need a scroll bar... the screen would now 'JUMP' back to the top/lowest position of the website....

I wish to remove that 'JUMP' and replace it with a smooth scroll up animation.

I hope this has explained the problem.
Look forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) easily :

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementToScrollTo").offset().top
}, 500);
```

Comment: As the content is dynamic, there wouldn't be such an element to set in the #elementToScrollTo?

Comment: @Josh90 You obviously have a container to load content in. That container would be the elementToScrollTo since you want to scroll on top of this container (top of the content)